# Google Sheet getValue() function slows down gradually

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google Sheet script with JavaScript to process some data. I notice its getValue() function takes long time to run, particularly when running multiple times for different cells. Following is the test function I have.

```
function timeTest (num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');

  var log = '';
  var preSec = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

  for (var i = 4; i < num; i++) {
     var fc = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue(); // values are like 100, 110,120 etc
     if (i % 20 == 0) {
        var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        var secDiff = seconds - preSec;
        log = log + "row " + i + " " + secDiff + "\n";
     }
  }

  return log;
}
```

I got results below. Basically, every 20 rows takes longer and longer time to run.
      row 20 0.07800006866455078
      row 40 0.08800005912780762
      row 60 0.0989999771118164
      row 80 0.1100001335144043
      row 100 0.12199997901916504
      row 120 0.2090001106262207
      row 140 0.22099995613098145
      row 160 0.23099994659423828
      row 180 0.24200010299682617
      row 200 0.25300002098083496
      row 220 1.50600004196167
      row 240 3.064000129699707
      row 260 4.437000036239624
      row 280 5.789000034332275
      row 300 7.088000059127808
      row 320 8.038000106811523
      row 340 8.91100001335144
      row 360 9.603000164031982
      row 380 10.216000080108643
      row 400 10.258000135421753
      row 420 10.271000146865845
      row 440 10.282999992370605
      row 460 10.295000076293945
      row 480 10.308000087738037

If I commented the getValue() line, I got the following --- takes milliseconds to run
      row 20 0
      row 40 0
      row 60 0
      row 80 0
      row 100 0
      row 120 0
      row 140 0
      row 160 0
      row 180 0
      row 200 0.0009999275207519531
      row 220 0.0009999275207519531
      row 240 0.0009999275207519531
      row 260 0.0009999275207519531
      row 280 0.0009999275207519531
      row 300 0.0009999275207519531
      row 320 0.0009999275207519531
      row 340 0.0009999275207519531
      row 360 0.0019998550415039062
      row 380 0.0019998550415039062
      row 400 0.0019998550415039062
      row 420 0.0019998550415039062
      row 440 0.0019998550415039062
      row 460 0.0019998550415039062
      row 480 0.0019998550415039062

Any thoughts?
TIA